# Android Studio ¿Como envío datos al cambiar de fragment con View Pager?

Tags: android, android-fragment, viewpager

**DESCRIPCIÓN:**

Tengo una actividad con un **view pager** y debajo unos image view que son circulos los cuales se deberían colorear según la posición del fragment en la que el usuario esté posicionado con el view pager.

**PREGUNTA:**

Como puedo enviar datos a la actividad cuando se hagan los cambios de fragments en el view pager?

**EJEMPLO:**

Cuando se pase del primer fragment (en el view pager) hacia el segundo, el primer circulo dejaría de estar coloreado para que se coloree el segundo (representando que el usuario está posicionado en el segundo fragment).

**Adjunto el código JAVA del PlaceHolderFragment que cambia los fragmentos**

```
public class PlaceholderFragment_contenedor_app_info extends Fragment {

private model_contenedor_app_info modelo;

//PARA RETORNAR EL FRAGMENT SELECCIONADO
public static Fragment newInstance(int index) {
    Fragment fragment = null;

    switch(index){
        case 1:
            fragment = new fragment_sobre_nosotros();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new fragment_ofrecemos_comodidad();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new fragment_en_confianza();
            break;
    }

    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    modelo = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(model_contenedor_app_info.class);
    int index = 1;
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        index = getArguments().getInt("section_number");
    }
    modelo.setIndex(index);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sobre_nosotros, container, false);

    return root;
}
}
```

Comment: usa una interfaz, para comunicar datos con el activity.

Comment: Como se hace eso?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments?hl=es#EventCallbacks

Comment: Puede ser una interfaz o BroadcastReceiver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si estás usando "unas imágenes que son círculos" probablemente te interese ver el componente TabLayout ya que son marcadores de las páginas del ViewPager y cambian automáticamente cuando el usuario lo hace.

Si no es el caso, ViewPager dispone de un listener llamado addOnPageChangeListener que captura el cambio de tab:

```
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}

                public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}

                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    // Do your logic
                }
     });
```

En el método onPageSelected(int position), puedes comprobar el número de la página y si quieres notificárselo al fragment en ese momento, la comunicación puedes hacerla con una interfaz como te han comentado o con un ViewModel compartido si ya lo estás usando.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias. Pudiste solucionar mi problema y de una manera super sencilla!